# How to set background color for specific rows in QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to set color for specific rows in QTableWidget, like setAlternatingRowColors does, only I should be able to specify which rows and which color I want. I tried the following code

```
QBrush b (QColor(224,224,224));
item->setBackground( 0 , b );
item->setBackground( 1 , b );
item->setBackground( 2 , b );
```

but this code only populates the item columns with color, not the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

As Qt handles all the fields of a QTableWidget in distinct QTableWidgetItems, there simply is no way to affect a complete row in your table as trivial as you suggest here. As you seem to use only standard fields and no custom "specials", you could just iterate over a rows QTableWidgetItems and set their background one by one.

The more stylish way, which would accomodate your needs, would be to use the model/View Framework of Qt to obtain the background color via the data backend using QBackgroundRole. A good starting point for this would be: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

It may be harder to grasp the concept behind the MVC paradigm, but it is really flexible once mastered.